# Modelling a price matrix table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, matrix

I am trying to create an ecommerce product that takes orders for print jobs. I would like to create tables such as the ones here on solopress for example http://www.solopress.com/leaflet-printing/leaflets.html. I am just struggling a little with the logical steps of modelling this in a database.

Firstly how would I go about creating a table like that where the column options could be configured differently per product in a database without having to create an actual database table each time.

Secondly then what would be the best way to work it so that the prices change as in the example above, when you change between Unfolded and Folded - would this need to be two independent tables that get switched?

Answer (score 0):

For storing the prices I'd structure the table like this:

```
size enum('A3','A4','A5','A6','DL'),
min_qty INT,
sides ENUM('1','2'),
folded BOOL,
price DECIMAL(6,2)
```

with your primary key being size+min_qty+sides+folded.
Generating the webpage will involve PHP or similar and updating the price as options are chosen will involve javascript.  If you have specific questions about those they should probably be asked separately.

Comment: Ah I hadn't thought of enum, that could be useful. Can that be changed? I suppose it would just being changing the table structure.

Comment: Enums can be changed with ALTER COLUMN which isn't hard, but it seems unlikely you'll have more than two sides on a page

Comment: Ah ha, indeed :) but we may change the sizes available! Oh I've just thought in that case I perhaps don't need to define it as an enum, maybe the thing I'm most interested in is keying it on a combination of fields?

Comment: @Koorb Oh, I see why you asked then.  If you didn't want size to be an enum, you could create a separate `sizes` table and create a foreign key reference it so that invalid sizes can't be entered.  Another possible tweak would be to combine folded and price into a `features SET('Two-Sided','Folded')` column